GitHub Actions matrix job running despite false conditions
I am experiencing unexpected behavior in my GitHub Actions workflow where a job is being triggered despite all conditions evaluating to false. Specifically, the docker job starts even when all outputs from the changes job are false, which should prevent any of the matrix entries from running. Additionally, I am unable to access ${{ matrix.image }} when all conditions are false. Below is the relevant part of my workflow:
Problem Details:
The docker job is starting even when all the outputs from the changes job are false.
When all conditions are false, it seems I cannot access ${{ matrix.image }}.
Questions:
What could be the reason that the docker job is being triggered despite all conditions evaluating to false? Is there a better way to structure the conditions to prevent the docker job from running when no changes are detected in the relevant paths?
jobs:
  changes:
    name: Detect changes
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      library: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.library }}
      workers: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.workers }}
      collector: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.collector }}
      api: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.api }}
      webhook: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.webhook }}
      all: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.changes }}
    timeout-minutes: 30
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@692973e3d937129bcbf40652eb9f2f61becf3332 # v1.4.7

      - name:
        uses: dorny/paths-filter@de90cc6fb38fc0963ad72b210f1f284cd68cea36 # v3.0.2
        id: filter
        with:
          filters: |
            library:
              - 'package.json'
              - 'package-lock.json'
              - 'shared/**'
            workers:
              - 'workers/**'
              - 'prisma/**'
            collector:
              - 'collector/**'
            api:
              - 'api/**'
            webhook:
              - 'webhook/**'

  docker:
    name: Build and push Docker Images
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: changes
    timeout-minutes: 30
    strategy:
      matrix:
        image: 
          - collector
          - workers
          - api
          - webhook
        isCollector:
          - ${{ needs.changes.outputs.collector == 'true' || needs.changes.outputs.library == 'true'}}
        isWorker:
          - ${{ needs.changes.outputs.workers == 'true' || needs.changes.outputs.library == 'true'}}
        isApi:
          - ${{ needs.changes.outputs.api == 'true' || needs.changes.outputs.library == 'true' }}
        isWebhook:
          - ${{ needs.changes.outputs.webhook == 'true' || needs.changes.outputs.library == 'true'}}
        exclude:
          - isCollector: false
            image: collector
          - isWorker: false
            image: workers
          - isApi: false
            image: api
          - isWebhook: false
            image: webhook


When a dynamic matrix is empty, GitHub Actions runs a single job with an empty matrix context. This is done for a variety of reasons.
We can prevent a job run with an empty matrix by adding a conditional to the job that verifies that at least one matrix record exists. For the docker job  this conditional expression can be written like this:
docker:
  name: Build and push Docker Images
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  needs: changes
  timeout-minutes: 30
  if: |
    needs.changes.outputs.collector == 'true' ||
    needs.changes.outputs.library == 'true' ||
    needs.changes.outputs.workers == 'true' ||
    needs.changes.outputs.api == 'true' ||
    needs.changes.outputs.webhook == 'true'
  strategy:
    matrix:
      image: 
        - collector
        - workers
        - api
        - webhook

